# Mysql select column from one table to match up with another table to pull id

Tags: php, mysql

What I am attempting to do is match the username stored in two tables, `table1` and `table2` and then pull the `user_id` of table 2.

`Table1` has columns such as `id`, `username`, and other random info

`Table2` has columns such as `user_id`, `username`, and other random info

What I am attempting to do in the end is select information from table1 to be displayed however so I can go to the correct id when i click the link I need the user_id out of table2

The following is pulling the user_id's however I need all of the other information out of Table1 so I can echo it out in my page

```
select user_id
from login_users
where username IN ( select username  from cpanel)
ORDER BY username DESC
```

Comment: I suggest to set table2 to be profiles. You are talking about one to one relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a join as below:

```
 SELECT b.user_id, a.*
 from cpanel a, 
    login_users b
 where b.username = a.username
 ORDER BY a.username DESC
```

OR

```
 SELECT b.user_id, a.*
 FROM cpanel a JOIN login_users b
   ON b.username = a.username
 ORDER BY a.username DESC
```

Here `a.*` returns you all the columns of `cpanel` table, while `userid` is retrieved from `login_users` table.

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TaylorReed Good. If this is helpful, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think the correct thing is
   select user_id2 from table2 where tablle1.username = table2.username and username = 'myname'